# Pentaho report contents not getting displayed in Pentaho user console? Why ? please answer

Tags: pentaho

I'm facing an error with a .prpt file.

While running the prpt in report designer it just works fine . 
But when the same prpt ran in PUC (user console), the report contents are not displayed.

It is a simple report containing total 8 columns with only text and number fields in the detail section and only labels (formulated also) in headers.

Please help with your valuable tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the server logs - there'll be an exception. I've seen this before - frequently it is due to layout issues, not sure why but for some reason in some cases the server bombs, yet the client does manage to render it.  Double check the obvious like overlapping elements etc.

Also check the version of your PRD client, and the exact version of the reporting libraries on the server, they MUST match.

Comment: I checked the layout issues and found perfect. There is no problem with layout or design. Number , text and date fields are assigned correctly. 

And more importantly, one similar report, developed along with this same report is working fine in user console.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when you have a prpt file that was created in an older (or newer) version of PRD than the server. You'll get javascript errors and onscreen you'll just see a blank page/tab. Make sure your version of PRD matches the server version.